# ObservableCollection remove item also after Catch

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, entity-framework-5

My project is a WPF project and I use the following code to remove the SelectedProducer form ProducerCollection (ObservableCollection).

```
   try
   {
       context.Producers.Remove(SelectedProducer);
       context.SaveChanges();
   }
   catch
   {
       messageService.Show("Error");
   }
```

and this is my collection and SelectedProducer property:

```
    public ObservableCollection<DAL.Domain.Producer> ProducerCollection
    {
        get { return GetValue<ObservableCollection<DAL.Domain.Producer>>(ProducerCollectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ProducerCollectionProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData ProducerCollectionProperty = RegisterProperty("ProducerCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<DAL.Domain.Producer>));

    [Model]
    public DAL.Domain.Producer SelectedProducer
    {
        get { return GetValue<DAL.Domain.Producer>(SelectedProducerProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(SelectedProducerProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData SelectedProducerProperty = RegisterProperty("SelectedProducer", typeof(DAL.Domain.Producer));
```

but in this way also when an error occured the collection remove the SelectedProdcuer.
How to handle this problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is expected - you remove an item from a collection and if the database call fails after that it will not magically reappear. You could manually reinsert the item inside the catch block or refetch the entire collection from the database.

You could also retry the save until it succeeds, but it is hard to tell what the best choice is without any context.